# Why is my counter == 0 after i incremented it in a loop?

Tags: javascript, html, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

In my HTML i have the following code:

```
<div id="userCount" class="number count-to" data-from="0" data-to="" data-speed="1000" data-fresh-interval="20"></div>
```

And in my Javascript i'm trying to get the registered users count to display it in ' data-to="" ' from firebase.

My Javascript code:

```
let db = firebase.firestore();
let count = 0;
var div = $('#userCount');

db.collection("users").get().then((snapShot) => {
   snapShot.forEach((doc) => {
      count++;
   });
});

div.data('to',count);
```

Why is that happening?

[image]

Comment: I think this is caused by the `let` keyword in declaration of the `count` variable. If you would use `var` keyword, it should exist throughout the contexts. I'm not sure tho

Answer (score 0):

Because db.collection function is asyncronized one. Please take a look at following solution

```
let db = firebase.firestore();
let count = 0;
var div = $('#userCount');

db.collection("users").get().then((snapShot) => {
   snapShot.forEach((doc) => {
      count++;
   });

   div.data('to',count);
});
```

Comment: It didn't work!

Comment: `count` is still 0?

Comment: Yes it's still 0

Comment: what is the length of `snapShot`?

Comment: Do you mean how many registered users there is?

Comment: I mean if `console.log(snapShot.length)`, what can you get?